# discord logs system on_messaged_edit with a few exclusion

Tags: python, discord.py

Here is the code that if a messages id edited, it will send to log channel that it was edited with the message before and after editing, also if after editing has a discord invite link it will delete it and send that to log channel and a dm to user, but i have a few exclusion, some roles can send discord invites, (allowed_roles) and this works, if i (allowed) edit a message and the edited message contains a discord invite link it will not deleted it, but it will count as edited, how can i make it so those allowed roles are ignored from edited messages ?

````
@client.event # Edited message logs
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
    author = after.author
    if "discord.gg" in after.content or "https://discord.gg/" in after.content or "discord.gg/" in after.content:
        has_role = False
        for role in author.roles:
            if role.id in allowed_roles:
                has_role = True
                break
        
        if not has_role:
            await after.delete()
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Message Deleted", description=f"A message from {author.mention} contained an invite link after editing and was deleted.\n\nOriginal message:\n{before.content}\nEdited message: \n{after.content}", color=discord.Color.red())
            embed.set_footer(text=footer_text, icon_url=footer_url)
            await client.get_channel(log_channel).send(embed=embed)
            dm = await after.author.create_dm()
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Warning", description=f"Advertising is not allowed in our server. Your message after editing has been deleted and a proof has been sent to the log channel.\n\nYour message:\n{after.content}", color=discord.Color.red())
            embed.set_footer(text=footer_text, icon_url=footer_url)
            await dm.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Message Edited", description=f"Original message sent by {author.mention}:\n{before.content}\nEdited message:\n{after.content}", color=discord.Color.red())
            embed.set_footer(text=footer_text, icon_url=footer_url)
            await client.get_channel(log_channel).send(embed=embed)
    ```
````

Comment: Why would this not work? Do you have the necessary roles in the particular channel? What is `allowed_roles`? Is it a list containing `id`s of roles, or is it a list containing the `name`s of roles? Note that [`Role.name`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Role.name) is not equal to [`Role.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Role.id). Use `print()` commands to check what's happening at various stages in your code. Add `print(has_role)`. If it's `False`, then `allowed_roles` is probably a list of roles' names, not roles' IDs.

Comment: Are you sure this is the full code? If you have an `else` for the `if role.id in allowed_roles:`, I guess when using the `for` loop to iterate through the roles of the author, as probably the roles are arranged in alphabetical order or an order that's not based on the power of the roles (it's probably not `everyone, moderator, AownerA`, it might be `AownerA, everyone, moderator`). So, when the last role is being checked, which can be `moderator` (assume that moderator is not allowed to edit or include invite links in the edits), as 'm' comes after 'A', `has_role` becomes false.

Comment: The allowed_roles are a list containt the role id.(i got every role and mentioned them in discord as <@&'id'>, and returned avalid roles from my server.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. Here is the finished code:

```
@client.event # Edited message logs
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
    author = after.author
    if "discord.gg" in after.content or "https://discord.gg/" in after.content or "discord.gg/" in after.content:
        has_role = False
        for role in author.roles:
            if role.id in allowed_roles:
                has_role = True
                break
        
        if not has_role:
            await after.delete()
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Message Deleted", description=f"A message from {author.mention} contained an invite link after editing and was deleted.\n\nOriginal message:\n{before.content}\nEdited message: \n{after.content}", color=discord.Color.red())
            embed.set_footer(text=footer_text, icon_url=footer_url)
            await client.get_channel(log_channel).send(embed=embed)
            dm = await after.author.create_dm()
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Warning", description=f"Advertising is not allowed in our server. Your message after editing has been deleted and a proof has been sent to the log channel.\n\nYour message:\n{after.content}", color=discord.Color.red())
            embed.set_footer(text=footer_text, icon_url=footer_url)
            await dm.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        has_role = False
        for role in author.roles:
            if role.id in allowed_roles:
                has_role = True
                break
        if not has_role:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Message Edited", description=f"Original message sent by {author.mention}:\n{before.content}\nEdited message:\n{after.content}", color=discord.Color.red())
            embed.set_footer(text=footer_text, icon_url=footer_url)
            await client.get_channel(log_channel).send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Please explain the code, how it is different from the code in your question and how it solves the problem. Please see [ask] and [answer], and edit your question and answer to help future readers.

Comment: Sure.
1. Condition cheking.
The first version checks for an invite link in the edited message using three or-joined conditions, while the second version employs an else block to handle cases where the message content lacks an invite link.

2. Code organization
The first version executes the entire code block when the condition is met, handling cases where the user lacks the required role and sending a warning, while the second version organizes the code into two branches for cases where the user lacks and has the required role.

Comment: Nice. It's usually better to include everything in the answer instead of comments.